# Can a Matlab PARFOR loop be programmatically switched on/off?

Tags: matlab, parfor

Have a simple question about parfor in MATLAB. I would like to set a flag in my program to change between parfor and regular for loops. Basically, I need this functionality so that some parts of my code can update graphics in a "debug" mode, then when the flag is turned off, use parfor with no graphics updates for speed.

So, I'm looking for something simple that has this functionality:

```
if (flag)
  for i = 1:n
else
  parfor i = 1:n
end

  % Do loop tasks.

  end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does reserving a pool size of 1 solve your problem?

Comment: Not exactly because parfor restricts creating any graphical objects, such as plots. Therefore, whenever I desire this output, I have to manually edit the code of the function.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible. However, if you can wrap the loop body in a separate function, you can have either a `parfor` or a `for` loop call the body, i.e.

```
if (flag)
   parfor i=1:n
      out(i) = loopBody(i)
   end
else
   for i=1:n
      out(i) = loopBody(i)
   end
end
```

Alternatively, you can edit the code so that you have either `parfor` or `for` in front of your loop, which is what I often end up doing.

Comment: If it was April 1, I would comment like "I wish MATLAB had `#define`s! then we could `#define LOOP parfor` or `#define LOOP for` and we wouldn't have this issue!"

Comment: @Li-aungYip: yes, this would indeed be convenient. `parfor` sucks for debugging. I expect that around R2015a, the problem is fixed, though.

Answer (score 6):

One more option - use the optional argument to [PARFOR](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parfor.html)

```
if flag
  arg = Inf;
else
  arg = 0;
end
parfor (idx = 1:n, arg)
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

When you close the pool by `matlabpool close`, `parfor` behaves just like a `for` and allows all graphics handling. So you just need to close the pool while debugging.

Comment: `parfor` does not behave just like `for`, even when there is no pool of workers. The order of the loop iterations is not guaranteed and they can be executed in any order. Typically, just to ensure that you don't rely on them being in the normal order, they are actually executed in *reverse* order.

Comment: Note that this is no longer quite true - recent versions of MATLAB & PCT *can* automatically open a pool for you, so you might need to use the optional number of workers argument to `parfor` as per my answer.