# Can 'for' loops be disabled depending on user input?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

Similar to this question:

[Can a Matlab PARFOR loop be programmatically switched on/off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133340/can-a-matlab-parfor-loop-be-programmatically-switched-on-off)

I'd like to know if I can use something similar for regular for-loops. Unfortunately I don't actually have a working copy of Matlab at the moment so I can't test this in my own code!

```
if (flag)
  for i = 1:n
else
  parfor i = 1:n
end

  % Do loop tasks.

  end
```

EDIT -

(Upon further reflection, I've put greater detail into my question)

This is what I currently have:

```
for i = 1:numel(Ffi)
    Ff = Ffi(i)

    for j = 1:numel(RelToli)
        RelTol = RelToli(j)

        for k = 1:numel(ki)
            k=ki(k)

                 % solve

        end
    end
end
```

I want to change it so that the user can choose a single value for Ff/RelTol/k directly (via GUI/requested input) or, if not specified by the user, to use all values in a pre-defined array (Ffi/RelToli/ki respectively) via a for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that that will not work. But this will:

```
for i = 1:(flag*n + ~flag)
```

So looking at `(flag*n + ~flag)`, if flag is true it will equal `n` (i.e. `1*n + 0`) and if flag is false is will equal `1` (`0*n + 1`)

**EDIT**

For your updated question:

Set a flag if the user enters a value and then

```
if flag
    F = Ff; %//i.e. user input scalar
else
    F = Ffi; %//i.e. Whole vector
end
```

now:

```
for Ff = F
```

Comment: Ok, I've looked at the code I currently have (in Notepad) and I've thought more closely about how I actually want to change it. I'll edit the original question.

Comment: oooo perfect. thanks a lot, this looks like just what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
if flag
    limit = n;
else
    limit = 1;
end

for i = 1:limit
    ...
end
```

Comment: This looks closer to what I had in mind, I'll have a think. Thanks very much